# How to enable native automation in testcafe studio

Tags: testcafe

How to enable native operation in testcafe ide?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a Testcafe team. At the moment, TestCafe Studio cannot use the native automation mode. We have plans to add it in the next release. Please follow our updates.